# Virtual memory on windows 10

Tags: memory, virtual-memory, windows-10-v1511

I've read on many articles and i've seen on my previous PC that the default Windows virtual memory formula is : 1.5 X RAM Size (for initial size).
But on my new Pc with 6GB of RAM , with windows 10 x64 v1511 , the recommended  Virtual memory Size is 1663 MB and allocated is 6144 MB.

Is there any change on Virtual memory size on windows 10 , or i'm misunderstand something ?

Comment: You can indeed change it, same way as always, it's in the exact same spot.  Who do you want to change it?  A 6 GB page file is plenty for your system.

Comment: I'm asking why Windows recommend 1663MB for Virtual memory in a Pc with 6GB RAM ? Usually it will recommend 6GB x 1.5.

Comment: If I were to hazard to guess.  At some point the Virtual Memory setting was changed from allowing Windows to handle the setting to it being set to manual.  Honestly, there is no general rule about Virtual Memory, your formula isn't even that standard.  I have 32 GB of memory installed and my page file is 61,903 MB how large your Page file primarily depends on your system storage space.

Comment: This may be a duplicate question: http://superuser.com/questions/1090569/what-is-the-optimal-virtual-memory-size-for-8-gb-ram-win-10/1090580#1090580... As far as I know, then general rule for Windows Page File size is the same as it's been as you indicate 1.5 times your RAM size but yes, if you have disk space constraints then that may be an issue. Allowing the system to manage this setting for home based PCs should be adequate enough though.

Comment: this 1.5 rule is crap. Let Windows manage the size and be happy