# Is the virtual memory page size too low on Parallels 18 VM for Apple M1 running Windows 11 ARM?

Tags: windows-11, virtual-memory, parallels, arm

I am running Windows 11 ARM inside an Apple M1 mac mini with 16 GB RAM.

My specs on Windows 11 look like this
[image]

One of the games that I am running specifically (Ghost Recon Future Soldier DX9) gives me a good 40-60 FPS but every few minutes the FPS drops to 1 FPS (basically freezes for a 3-4 seconds)

I noticed that the virtual memory paging size has been set to just 1664 MB by default by Parallels VM for Apple M1 version 18
[image]

**Questions**

1. What is the right amount of paging size that I could increase to?
2. Could this be the reason that the FPS drops because the game runs of virtual memory and has to write to the HDD every now and then?

Comment: _"because the game runs of virtual memory"_ - no, because then it would crash. But it could be running out of physical memory, ie. RAM.

Comment: 6GB of RAM allocated to it could mean that it is paging to disk. Increasing page file size won't help, giving it more actual RAM will.

Comment: The right amount of RAM will depend on the game and can only be determined by testing.

Comment: @harrmyc the requirements of the game shoudnt be a problem https://imgur.com/a/RsOWu5E when your page size is low what does it actually do? another question says something entirely different https://superuser.com/questions/1090569/what-is-the-optimal-virtual-memory-size-for-8-gb-ram-win-10

Comment: @PirateApp those specifications are based on Windows Vista which had a much smaller memory footprint of 512-1024MB (1GB). Windows 11 requires 4GB or greater as a minimum and then you need more to be "comfortable". If your swap is too small or disabled then you will get "out of memory" errors, not stuttering or poor performance. Poor performance is a sign that it is *using* swap, not that you don't have enough. Swap is not a good substitute for real RAM.

Comment: Your other problem is probably running an x86 game on an ARM processor which will mean that Windows is converting architectures which will also mean a performance hit on top of everything. Your problem is not swap related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is unlikely to be related to your swap file being too small. If the swap were too small then you would be seeing "out of memory" errors rather than slowness or performance drops.

Slowness *can be* a sign of actually *using* the swap file, but not the swap file being too small.

But in your case the problem is simpler. You are running an x86 CPU architecture game on ARM hardware.

You have an ARM processor, running an ARM operating system (macOS), and then virtualising another operating system within that (Windows 11 ARM).

You are, due to its age, unlikely to be able to find a "native" ARM version of the game you are playing. That means that Windows must essentially recompile the code meant for a different CPU architecture to run. That process takes time and effort and is generally considered [not great](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/q4c9vx/why_windows_on_arm_x86_emulation_is_so_bad_while/). It can be bearable, but you shouldn't consider it flawless for time critical things like gaming.