Software on Windows crashing/OOMing with RAM well below 100%
I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon (4th gen, 2016), and lately while working I've been noticing Chrome and PyCharm intermittently crashing.
Usually it seems like like a CPU spike or something causes the entire program to crash. It'll happen when I open a new tab in Chrome, or start writing code in a search window in PyCharm that would cause its error-checking routines to start looking for problems with what I've written. In other words, it seems to be when the CPU is suddenly getting strained.
Today I noticed Chrome tabs saying they don't have enough memory to open while my RAM usage was at 80% (see the image below). It seemed to be around when Windows Compatibility Telemetry was starting to run, but that could be me misremembering. In any case, I don't understand how to reconcile the error message with what Windows is telling me my RAM usage is.
How can I go about troubleshooting these apparent CPU/RAM issues? Why are these programs crashing when CPU momentarily hits 100% instead of just slowing down / pausing (assuming that's what's causing some of the crashes)? Why would Chrome tell me there's not enough memory when RAM usage is well below 100%?

Below is what my page file settings show:


Did you perhaps disable the page file?

80% RAM usage is high and the system will do to many page swapping. Program can crash due to out of memory and CPU usage can be high because of too much page swapping.

Thank you for your comments. @DanielB I added a screenshot showing my page file settings. So no, I don't seem to have the page file disabled.

@rint But why would the program run out of memory if there's 3.2GB of RAM available (I have 16GB on my laptop so at 80% used there should be 3.2GB free) plus the page file?

If your page file is enabled, all is well. // You could check your RAM with Memtest86 and stress test your CPU using Prime95 or the like. If the problem is tied to load spikes, it could also be the PSU that is failing.

Set your page file to "System managed size" or increase it to something more sensible for your system, 8GB or larger. By setting it too small your problem is essentially the same as having disabled the page file.

Your problem is that programs over-allocate memory and Windows mandates that any memory allocation must have storage (RAM or page file) to back up that allocation. By limiting your page file you limit the amount of memory programs can allocate. Increase the size of your page file or let the system deal with it and your problems will go away. There is no reason to limit it to 3GB when you have 600GB free on that drive.

https://superuser.com/questions/1090569/what-is-the-optimal-virtual-memory-size-for-8-gb-ram-win-10

@DanielB You were right to begin with, the problem is with the page file in that it is as good as disabled. It is there, but far too small for the system.

@Mokubai & DanielB Thank you both so much for your help, I've increased my page file to the recommendation in that link (1024 * 16 * 1.5 = 24,576 MB) and I'll report back within the next few days.

@Mokubai &DanielB I'm having no issues at all while working today (no crashes at all), I feel like I have a brand-new computer. Task manager seems to be indicating I'm using ~4GB of the page file while in my normal work setup (on the Task Manager Performance tab, in the Memory section, "In-use" is at 11.1GB while "Committed" is at 15.2GB out of 39.9GB, so 15.2 - 11.1 = 4.1). Thank you both again so much for your help, I'll wait a day to give Mokubai the chance to post his comments as the answer so he gets any future upvotes, otherwise I'll post the answer myself.

Another interesting thing is that my RAM usage is now hovering at around 70% where previously it was hovering at around 80%.

The problem was that my page file was too small. After increasing the size of my page file, the problem went away entirely.
I increased the size to the recommended 1.5x my RAM (I have 16GB of RAM, so 1024MB/GB * 16GB * 1.5 = 24,576 MB), and afterwards saw my page file usage hovering around 4GB, while previously its total size was set to 2.9GB.
From Mokubai in the comments:

Set your page file to "System managed size" or increase it to something more sensible for your system, 8GB or larger. By setting it too small your problem is essentially the same as having disabled the page file.
our problem is that programs over-allocate memory and Windows mandates that any memory allocation must have storage (RAM or page file) to back up that allocation. By limiting your page file you limit the amount of memory programs can allocate. Increase the size of your page file or let the system deal with it and your problems will go away. There is no reason to limit it to 3GB when you have 600GB free on that drive.
What is the Optimal Virtual Memory Size For 8 GB RAM | WIN 10?
the problem is with the page file in that it is as good as disabled. It is there, but far too small for the system.

